# Code question about wye and 90 degree elbow

Tags: drain, code-compliance

Can a 90 degree elbow be placed right next to a Wye?  The toilet drains into main branch by a wye. It immediately goes into a 90 elbow to drop the main branch down to the sewer.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a diagram or picture of what you're hoping to do?